# What optics are used in Microsoft HoloLens?

Tags: hardware

How does Microsoft project an image so close to the eye yet understandable by the brain?

How is the display transparent?

This link has good information but is speculative. https://www.reddit.com/r/HoloLens/comments/2v0nac/hololens_display_tech_and_what_to_expect_from_it/

What materials are used?

For a list of patents see this: http://vrwiki.wikispaces.com/Microsoft+HoloLens